# Fixed points of the equation $x' = rx \ln(K/x)$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

$$x'\ =\ r\cdot x\cdot \ln\left(\frac{ {K} }{x}\right)$$

Analyze fixed points and their stability depending on the parameters.
I found one fixed point $x = K$ and the stability of this point. If $r < 0 \implies$ $x=K$ is unstable, if $r > 0\implies$ $x=K$ is  stable.

And I know that second fixed point should be $x=0$, but I'm not sure how to determine it's stability. If someone could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Homework questions are not adapted to MathOverflow. You should post on MathStackExchange instead.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632150/x-rx-lnk-x-fixed-points.